# Category Hierarchy with Selected and Disable Mode (PHP-MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical-data

I use this code to make dropdown list like this, support selected parent when update mode

Current category dropdown (select category 1.1 a child of category 1)
[image]

```
public static function dropdown($parent, $child = null) {
        static $level = 0;
        static $return = '';

        $search = self::all(array('parent' => $parent, 'status' => 1));

        foreach ($search as $data) {
            $level--;

            $space = '';

            for($i = 1; $i < ($level*-1); $i++) $space .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';

            if ($child == $data->id) $selected = 'selected';
            else $selected = '';

            $return .= '<option value="'.$data->id.'" '.$selected.'>'.$space.'- '.$data->name.'</option>';

            self::dropdown($data->id, $child);

            $level++;
        }

        return $return;
    }
```

Problem : How to disable all child of category 1.1 and him self when i update category 1.1 ??

Goal screenshot : 
[image]

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve, can you clarify a bit ?

Comment: I need category dropdown like screenshot goal. When i update category 1.1, category 1.1 and all child disable

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public static function dropdown($parent, $child = null, $isSelected=false) {
    static $level = 0;
    static $return = '';

    $search = self::all(array('parent' => $parent, 'status' => 1));

    foreach ($search as $data) {
        $level--;

        $space = '';

        for($i = 1; $i < ($level*-1); $i++) $space .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';

        if ($child == $data->id || $isSelected){
            $selected = 'selected';
            $isSelected = true;
        }else{
            $selected = '';
        }

        $return .= '<option value="'.$data->id.'" '.$selected.'>'.$space.'- '.$data->name.'</option>';

        self::dropdown($data->id, $child, $isSelected);

        $level++;
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Basically you have to transfer the status (selected or not) of the current node, and transfers it to his childs.